# multiplying 2 int types results in a num type

Tags: dart

I'm currently studying Dart and practicing what I learned by doing coding challenges at codewars.com.

One of the basic challenges that I'm trying to solve is to create a function that will convert a binary string to its decimal equivalent.

The initial solution (albeit, not optimal) that I wrote involved the following code:

```
int binToDec(bin) {
  int dec = 0;
  for (int i = bin.length-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
    
    dec += (int.parse(bin[i]) * pow(2, j));
  }
  return dec;
}
```

Running the code though (whether in codewars.com or DartPad) will give out the following error:

```
Error: A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
    dec += (int.parse(bin[i]) * pow(2, j));
        ^
```

I was able to fix this by adding a toInt() method to the right side of the equation:

```
dec += (int.parse(bin[i]) * pow(2, j)).toInt();
```

My question is, why did the compiler mention that I'm assigning a num type value to the 'dec' variable when the runtimeType of (int.parse(bin[i]) * pow(2, j)) is an int type?

i.e.:

> print((int.parse(bin[i]) * pow(2, j)).runtimeType);

would print the following result in the Dartpad console:

> int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, why did the compiler mention that I'm assigning a num type value to the 'dec' variable when the runtimeType of (int.parse(bin[i]) * pow(2, j)) is an int type?

Because the compiler doesn't know what the runtime type is.  The runtime type, by definition, is known *at runtime*.

[`pow`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-math/pow.html) is declared to return a `num`, so that's the type known at compile-time.  Depending on the arguments given (see the documentation), `pow` can return an `int` at runtime, but it's impractical for the compiler to know for what combinations of arguments `pow` returns `int` and for what combinations it returns `double`.  You therefore must cast its result when you know what to expect: `dec += (int.parse(...) * (pow(2, j) as int));`

Comment: There are some special functions where the compiler *does* know something extra about, say `int * int` is an `int` and `int.clamp(int, int)` is an `int`, even though `int.operator*` has return type `num`. 
The `pow` function is not included in that distinguished collection because it's not the case that `pow(int, int)` is always an `int`, it requires knowing the actual *value* to say that, because `pow(2, -1)`, with two integer arguments, is the double 0.5.